# Segmentation Fault accessing 2-D Array

Tags: c

I am trying to write 4 bytes at a time to a character buffer using a integer pointer (So that I can access 4 memory locations at a time).
But I am getting a segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
unsigned char ssdData[2][10];
unsigned int** cur_ptr;

printf("1\n");
cur_ptr=ssdData;
printf("2\n");
**cur_ptr=(unsigned int)5;
printf("3\n");
printf("cur_ptr=%d",cur_ptr[0][0]);
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which environment ? no error on Windows, mingw gcc 4.6.1

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? You're creating a 2D character array, assigning a single `unsigned int` to it, then treating the pointer to the `int` as if it were a 2D integer array, and trying to print the first element of it (using the wrong `printf` specifier). What is it you actually want to do? And why are you switching between all these types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is you think that arrays are pointers and that 2D arrays are double pointers. That's incorrect, [read this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

If you want to access the first element of a two-dimensional array, then use

```
arr[0][0] = 5;
```

or the equivalent

```
**arr = 5;
```

**where `arr` is the array.** If it's a pointer, the you need to declare and use it like this:

```
int (*ptr)[10] = &arr[0];
(*ptr)[0] = 5;
// or:
**ptr = 5;
```

Or like this:

```
int *ptr = arr[0];
ptr[0] = 5;
// or:
*ptr = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 unsigned int** cur_ptr;
 **cur_ptr=(unsigned int)5;
 printf("cur_ptr=%d",cur_ptr[0][0]);
```

to

```
 unsigned int * cur_ptr;
 *cur_ptr=(unsigned int)5;
 printf("cur_ptr=%d",cur_ptr[0]); //or printf("cur_ptr=%d", *cur_ptr);
```

Use single pointer for `cur_ptr` instead of double pointer. You want `cur_ptr` pointing to integer number not to array/pointers of pointer to integer.

Comment: @Rohan--I did that, I am still getting Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Please leave an explanation that why should OP do that ?

Comment: @JayK, you need to change `printf()` too, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `cur_ptr` as a pointer to a pointer to an `unsigned int`.
You then initialize `cur_ptr` to the array `ssdData` which decays in the expression to the address of `ssData`.  So your memory looks like this:

```
cur_ptr--> | ssdData[0][0] | ssdData[0][1] | . . . | ssData[1][9] |
```

When you assign to `**cur_ptr` you are assigning to the memory location pointed to by the memory location pointed to by `cur_ptr`.  Thus, you read the first portion of the contents `ssData` as an address and try to assign to that location.  The first portion of the contents of `ssData` are uninitialized garbage at this point.  So you are trying to write to some random memory location that is causing a segmentation fault.

Comment: -Solved my doubt. Understood my mistake.